# Check 2 numbers algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, algorithm, bookshelf.js

I have 2 fields on db. Minor and Major:

```
Minor, Major
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0
5,0
7,0
8,0
...
65536,0
0,1
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,1
...
65536,1
0,2
```

What is best way to compare this. I am doing this on [Bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/) but in php or ruby also is welcome. I need to check current situation, get greater major and add minor + 1, if is not 65536 else minor is 0 major gets major + 1.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
I have to save major and minor to respective fields. They increment for every user registered.

eg. 
    Users

```
id, username,minor,major
1,  john , 0, 0
2, mike, 1, 0
....
65537, jeff, 65536,0
```

Now Tom's ,major increments becuse last minor on table is 65536.

```
65538, tom, 0 , 1
```

I don't know how to explain more.

Comment: Do you want to generate a file with these 2 fields, or do you want an existing file processed in some way? It is not clear from your question what are you aiming for.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are asking two questions: 1. Given a list of these (major, minor) pairs, find the maximum, and 2. Given the maximum (major, minor) pair,  get the next one?

Comment: This appears to be an entirely predictable set, so why store it at all? An RDBMS seems irrelevant here (besides, if it was me, I'd list the major column first)

Comment: As I edited question, when new user is register gets last minor +1. Kinda of autoincrement but limit to 65536 and when it reaches 65536 resets to 0 and increment major + 1

Comment: After doing some more research, I found that UNSIGNED SMALLINT = 65535. I will check to see if it works.

Comment: We obviously have some trouble understanding *what* you are trying to do. Maybe you should edit your question to put less emphasis on *how* you attempted to solve it, and explain more clearly the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm absolutely *not* sure to understand the problem, but here are some ideas about limiting the range of an integer value:

- Like many languages, MySQL has some [UNSIGNED SMALLINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) data types that holds 2-bytes values, that is from 0 to 65535 (**not** 65536 !)
- Most programming laguage have a "modulus" operator (`%` -- [php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)) that allow you to collect the rest of an integral division. For example, `... % 65536` will return a value between 0 and 65535 incl. If you really need a value between 0 and 65536 incl, you will write `... % 65537` instead.
- You could use *mask* operator ("bitwise and" `&` -- [php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and)). For example, `... & 0xFFFF` will only keep the two lowest significant bytes of a number -- actually performing the equivalent of a "modulo 65536" operation (having a result between 0 and 65535 incl.)

Comment: You are correct about 2-byte values, let me check how I can work with that. here is my logic. get greater major, let say 2, get greater minor where major is 2, increment minor + 1.

Comment: After I did some test, my last comment worked, I used UNSIGNED SMALLINT and did 2 queries, since I cannot do select in select in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$magicNumber = 65536;
$sql = "
SELECT
  MAX(userIndex) userIndex
FROM (
 SELECT 
   (Minor + (Major * ".$magicNumber.")) AS userIndex
 FROM TableName
) AS innerSelect
";
```

running the sql gives you the currently highest userIndex, let's say it is 145323.
Now increment this by one, and you have `$newIndex = 145324`.

This gives you the currently highest Index. Now the fields can be calculated like this:

```
$major = (int)($newIndex / $magicNumber);
$minor = $newIndex % $magicNumber;
```

Comment: Michael I ignored your answer just because I cannot do select in select with orm I am using, or dont know how. Thanks anyway.